# Memory address of strings declared using a char pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I read that when you declare strings using a pointer, the pointer contains the memory address of the string literal. Therefore I expected to get the memory address from this code but rather I got some random numbers. Please help me understand why it didn't work.

```
int main()
{
    char *hi = "Greeting!";
    printf("%p",hi);
    return(0);
}
```

If the pointer `hi` contains the memory address of the string literal, then why did it not display the memory address?

Comment: _but rather I got some random numbers_...What is your output?

Comment: What do you expect a memory address to look like if not a bunch of random numbers?

Comment: The char pointer points to the address of the string literal. It doesn't contain the address

Comment: @SeekAddo, it points to the string, which is another way of saying it contains the string's address.  "Points to the address" would be a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: Sorry guys, the address was 0000000000404000. Because I did not see a letter A through F in it, I was under the impression that it was not a hex. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It did work. It's just that you can consider the address as being arbitrarily chosen by the C runtime. `hi` is a pointer set to the address of the capital `G` in your string. You own all the memory from `hi` up to and including the nul-terminator at the end of that string.

Also, use `const char *hi = "Greeting!";` rather than `char *`: the memory starting at `hi` is *read-only*. Don't try to modify the string: the behaviour on attempting to do that is *undefined*.

Answer (score 0):

The "random numbers" you got are the Memory addresses. They are not constant, since on each execution of your program, other Memory addresses are used.

Answer (score 0):

A pointer could be represented in several ways. The format string `"%p"` *"writes an implementation defined character sequence defining a pointer"* [link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf). In most cases, it's the pointed object's address interpreted as an appropriately sized unsigned integer, which looks like "a bunch of random number".

A user readable pointer representation is generally only useful for debugging. It allows you to compare two different representations (are the pointers the same?) and, in some cases, the relative order and distance between pointers (which pointer comes "first", and how far apart are they?). Interpreting pointers as integers works well in this optic.

It would be helpful to us if you could clarify what output you expected. Perhaps you expected pointers to be zero-based?

Note that, while some compilers might accept your example, it would be wiser to use `const char *`. Using a `char *` would allow you to try to modify your string literal, which is undefined behavior.